# How to handle error when using router and useLocation hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Doing TicTacToe game. In the intro page with the URL `"/"` I have a component which picks the value `pickIndex` and carries to `"/game"` when clicking either `<ButtonMultiplayer />` or `<ButtonCPU />`. The code works fine unless I manually change the URL to `"/game"` without submitting `pickIndex` value. Doing so I get an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickIndex')". This error happens even when I am playing inside the `"/game"`, then changing the URL to some invalid value (getting 404 error), and then setting the URL back to `"/game"` - it seems that `pickIndex` value resets to `null`..

Below is my component of the Intro page.

```
export default function IntroView() {
    const id = useId();
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [pickIndex, setPickIndex] = useState("");
    const levelRef = useRef("")
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
            <form>
                <div className={styles.pickMarkBox}>
                    <p>PICK PLAYER 1'S MARK</p>
                    <div className={styles.buttonBox}>
                        <ButtonMark
                            classInput="P1"
                            value="xButton"
                            classLabel={styles.player1}
                            markId={id + 'x'}
                            isActive={pickIndex === 'x'}
                            onClick={() => {
                                setPickIndex('x');
                                setIsDisabled(false);
                            }}
                        />
                        <ButtonMark
                            classInput="P2"
                            value="zeroButton"
                            classLabel={styles.player2}
                            markId={id + 'zero'}
                            isActive={pickIndex === 'zero'}
                            onClick={() => {
                                setPickIndex('zero');
                                setIsDisabled(false);
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <p>REMEMBER: X GOES FIRST</p>
                </div>
                < ButtonMultiplayer
                    value="NEW GAME VS PLAYER"
                    className={`${styles.gameMode} ${styles.newGameVsPlayer}`}
                    disabled={isDisabled}
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        navigate("/game", { state: { gameMode: 'vsPlayer', pickIndex } });
                    }}
                />
                <ButtonCPU
                    disabled={isDisabled}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        // setLevel(e.target.value)
                        levelRef.current = e.target.value
                        navigate("/game", { state: { gameMode: 'vsCPU', pickIndex, levelRef } })
                    }}
                    value={levelRef}
                />
            </form >
        </div >
    );
}
```

In `"/game"` I use useLocation to retrieve the param passed from the intro page.

```
export default function Board(src) {
   const mark = useLocation().state.pickIndex;
...
}
```

Question: how to handle possible errors when the user manually changes the URL into `"/game"` while on the intro page?
Also is there a reason I should not use `useLocation` and switch instead to `useParams`?

I have tried using the following, and this is what I would ideally expect to happen.

```js
if (useLocation().state.pickIndex === null) {
  navigate("/")
}
```

but this does not work.
I also tried storing in sessionStorage but no result either.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `location.state` is potentially null/undefined, so you often can't just directly access route state properties. When URLs are entered directly there will be no passed route state to access.

Extract the route state first, ***then*** check the appropriate state value and issue a back navigation if missing as an ***intentional*** side-effect.

Example:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { state } = useLocation();

const { pickIndex } = state || {};

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!pickIndex) {
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
    // or navigate(-1) to issue a POP to the previous page
  }
}, [navigate, pickIndex]);

...

// Conditionally return early to guard UI if necessary
if (!pickIndex) return null;

...
```

or

```
const { state } = useLocation();

const { pickIndex } = state || {};

...

// Conditionally return redirect to home
if (!pickIndex) {
  return <Navigate to="/" replace />
};

...
```